# Estado HTTP 401 y org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException en Spring Security + JWT

Tags: java, jwt, spring-security

Hola a todas y a todos.

Estoy generando Roles y Permisions para gestionar usuarios. Genero el token JWT, partiendo de un usuario Admin dado de alta en la BD; pero cuando realizo una petición API para obtener una lista de ellos, salta estos errores: 401 y LazyInitializationException. A continuación, comparto varios códigos fuente:

**Spring Console**

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.practicas.conexiona.model.User.userGroups, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.isEmpty(PersistentSet.java:174) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at com.practicas.conexiona.model.User.getPermissionList(User.java:206) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.practicas.conexiona.model.User.getAuthorities(User.java:115) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.practicas.conexiona.service.UserService.loadUserByUsername(UserService.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.practicas.conexiona.security.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
```

**User.class**

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private String userId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "accountId", referencedColumnName = "accountId", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Account account;

    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "emailAddress")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    @ColumnDefault(value = "1")
    private Integer enabled;

    @Column(name = "lastLogin")
    private Long lastLogin;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Set<UserGroupUser> userGroups = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User (String userId, String accountId, String userName, String emailAddress, String password, Integer enabled, Long lastLogin) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.account = new Account(accountId);
        this.userName = userName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
    }

    public User(String userId, Account account, String userName, String emailAddress, String password, Integer enabled, Long lastLogin) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.account = account;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
    }

    public User(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Account getAccount() { return account; }

    public void setAccount(Account account) { this.account = account; }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        // Extract list of permissions (name)
        this.getPermissionList().forEach(p -> {
            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(p);
            authorities.add(authority);
        });

        // Extract list of roles (ROLE_name)
        this.getRoleList().forEach(r -> {
            GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + r);
            authorities.add(authority);
        });

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.getEnabled() == 1;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Integer enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Long getLastLogin() {
        return lastLogin;
    }

    public void setLastLogin(Long lastLogin) {
        this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
    }

    public Set<UserGroupUser> getUserGroups() {
        return userGroups;
    }

    public void setUserGroups(Set<UserGroupUser> userGroupUser) {
        this.userGroups = userGroupUser;
    }



    public List<String> getRoleList(){
        List<String> userRoleList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!userGroups.isEmpty()) {
            for (UserGroupUser usu : userGroups) {
                if (usu.getUserAdmin() == 1)
                    userRoleList.add("ADMIN");
                else
                    userRoleList.add("GUEST");
            }
            return userRoleList;
        } else {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public List<String> getPermissionList(){
        List<String> userPermissionsList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!userGroups.isEmpty()) {
            for (UserGroupUser usu : userGroups) {
                if (usu.getUserAdmin() == 1) {
                    userPermissionsList.add("PERM_CREATE_ACCOUNT");
                    userPermissionsList.add("PERM_READ_ACCOUNT");
                    userPermissionsList.add("PERM_READ_ALL_ACCOUNTS");
                    userPermissionsList.add("PERM_UPDATE_ACCOUNT");
                    userPermissionsList.add("PERM_DELETE_ACCOUNT");
                    userPermissionsList.add("PERM_CREATE_USER");
                    userPermissionsList.add("PERM_READ_USER");
                    userPermissionsList.add("PERM_READ_ALL_USERS");
                    userPermissionsList.add("PERM_UPDATE_USER");

                } else {
                    userPermissionsList.add("PERM_READ_ALL_USERS");
                }
            }
            return userPermissionsList;
        } else {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

}
```

**UserGroupUser.class**

```
@Entity(name="UserGroupUser")
@Table

public class UserGroupUser implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserGroupUserId userGroupUserId = new UserGroupUserId();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("userGroupId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "userGroupId", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar(36)")
    private UserGroup userGroup;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar(36)")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "userAdmin")
    @ColumnDefault(value = "0")
    private Integer userAdmin;

    public UserGroupUser() {
    }

    public UserGroupUser(UserGroupUserId userGroupUserId) {
        this.userGroupUserId = userGroupUserId;
    }

    public UserGroupUser(String userId, String userGroupId) {
        this.userGroupUserId = new UserGroupUserId(userId, userGroupId);
    }

    public UserGroupUser(String userId, String userGroupId, Integer userAdmin) {
        this.userGroupUserId = new UserGroupUserId(userId, userGroupId);
        this.userAdmin = userAdmin;
    }


    public UserGroupUser(UserGroupUserId userGroupUserId, Integer userAdmin) {
        super();
        this.userGroupUserId= userGroupUserId;
        this.userAdmin = userAdmin;
    }

    public UserGroupUser(UserGroupUserId userGroupUserId, UserGroup userGroup, User user, Integer userAdmin) {
        this.userGroupUserId = userGroupUserId;
        this.userGroup = userGroup;
        this.user = user;
        this.userAdmin = userAdmin;
    }

    public UserGroupUserId getUserGroupUserId() {
        return userGroupUserId;
    }

    public void setUserGroupUserId(UserGroupUserId userGroupUserId) {
        this.userGroupUserId = userGroupUserId;
    }

    public UserGroup getUserGroup() {
        return userGroup;
    }

    public void setUserGroup(UserGroup userGroup) {
        this.userGroup = userGroup;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Integer getUserAdmin() {
        return userAdmin;
    }

    public void setUserAdmin(Integer userAdmin) {
        this.userAdmin = userAdmin;
    }
}
```

**UserGroupUserId.class (Tabla N:M con tabla UserGroup)**

```
@Embeddable
public class UserGroupUserId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "userId")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "userGroupId")
    private String userGroupId;

    public UserGroupUserId() {
    }

    public UserGroupUserId(String userId, String userGroupId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userGroupId = userGroupId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserGroupId() {
        return userGroupId;
    }

    public void setUserGroupId(String userGroupId) {
        this.userGroupId = userGroupId;
    }
}
```

**JwtRequestFilter.class**

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

        //Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set authentication
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint.class**

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7858869558953243875L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        try {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**JwtTokenUtil.class**

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2550185165626007488L;

    public static final long JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 5*60*60*60;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date getIssuedAtDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getIssuedAt);
    }

    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(new Date());
    }

    private Boolean ignoreTokenExpiration(String token) {
        // here you specify tokens, for that the expiration is ignored
        return false;
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .claim("authorities", authorities)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY*1000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret)
                .compact();
    }

    public Boolean canTokenBeRefreshed(String token) {
        return (!isTokenExpired(token) || ignoreTokenExpiration(token));
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers( "/api/v1/usermanage/**").hasRole("GUEST")
                .antMatchers( "/api/v1/accountmanage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/usermanage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.jwtUserDetailsService);

        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

**UserController.class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/usermanage")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_GUEST') OR hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.findAllUsers();
    }
}
```

**UserService.class**

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService, UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;


    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Referencia JWT+MySQL+Spring Security: https://www.techgeeknext.com/spring/spring-boot-security-token-authentication-jwt-mysql

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Viendo el stacktrace, el Controller no interviene en este fallo, pero sí lo hace el service. Lamentablemente has puesto todas las clases menos esa. ¿Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir el código de UserService para poder ayudarte a corregir el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado el error, se trata de poner @Transactional al método loadUserByUsername en UserService. Al sobrecargarlo de UserDetailsService, no traceaba el estado de esta llamada. @PabloLozano gracias como siempre, y disculpas por si no he visto a tiempo tu comentario. ;)

```
  @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
    }
```